# LTTng/Perf: Difference between events used for exiting (sched_process_exit) and freeing (sched_process_free) a process

Tags: linux-kernel, trace, perf, ftrace, lttng

Currently, I'm getting into the topic of kernel tracing with LTTng and Perf. I'm especially interested to trace the different states a process is in.

I stumbled over the event `sched_process_free` and `sched_process_exit`. I'm wondering if my current understanding is correct:

If a process is exited, `sched_process_exit` is written to the trace. However, the process descriptor might still be in the memory which leads to a zombie. When the whole memory connected to the process is freed, `sched_process_free` is called. This would mean, if I really want to be sure that the process is fully "terminated" and removed from memory, I have to listen to `sched_process_free` instead of `sched_process_exit` in the trace. Is this correct?

Comment: I'm a little confused why there is no reply. If you have any problem of the answer, please tell me so that we can improve it. If it's helpful to you, can you please give me a useful upvote or acception? That's important for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find some time to edit my answer to make it more clear. If there are still some problem, please tell me, we can discuss and make it more clear. Let's dive into the end of task :

there are two system calls : `exit_group()` and `exit()`, and all of them will go to `do_exit()`, which will do the following things.

- set `PF_EXTING` which means the task is deleting
- remove the task descriptor from timer by `del_timer_sync()`
- call `exit_mm(), exit_sem(), __exit_fs()` and others to release structure of that task
- call [perf_event_exit_task](https://code.woboq.org/linux/linux/kernel/events/core.c.html#perf_event_exit_task)([tsk](https://code.woboq.org/linux/linux/kernel/exit.c.html#73tsk));
- decrease the ref count
- set `exit_code` to `_exit()/exit_group()` or error
- call `exit_notify()`

  - update relationship with parent and child
  - check `exit_signal`, send `SIGCHLD`
  - if task is not traced or return value is -1, set the exit_state to `EXIT_DEAD`, call `release_task()` to recycle other memory and decrease ref count.
  - if task  is traced, set exit_state to `EXIT_ZOMBIE`
  - set task  flag to `PF_DEAD`
- call `schedule()`

We need zombie state cause the parent may need to use those file descriptors so we can not delete all the things in the first time. The parent task will need to use something like `wait()` to check if child is dead. After `wait()`, it is time for the zombie to release totally by `release_task()`

- decrease the owners' task number
- if the task is traced, delete from the `ptrace_children` list
- call `__exit_signal()` delete all pending signals and release signal_struct descriptor and `exit_itimers()` delete all the timer
- call `__exit_sighand()` delete signal handler
- call `__unhash_process()`

  - `nr_threads`--
  - call `detach_pid()` to delete task descriptor from `PIDTYPE_PID` and `PIDTYPE_TGID`
  - call `REMOVE_LINKS` to delete the task from list
- call `sched_exit()` to schedule parent's time pieces
- call `put_task-struct()` to decrease the counter, and release memory & task descriptor
- call [delayed_put_task_struct()](https://code.woboq.org/linux/linux/kernel/exit.c.html#224)

So, we know that `sched_process_exit` state will be make in the do_exit(), but we can not make sure if the process is released or not (may call release_task() or not, which will trigger `sched_process_free`). That is why we need both of the two perf event point.

Comment: Hi @tyChen, sorry for my late reply and thx for your answer. I have to confess that I currently do not get in which way this supports my thoughts? What am I missing here, can you point out the exact reason.

Comment: What do you think about [this code section](https://code.woboq.org/linux/linux/kernel/exit.c.html). We can find there the `release_task` with the call to `delayed_put_task_struct`, where we can find `trace_sched_process_free`?

Comment: Hi @tyChen, it seems like your last edit completes now my picture. I will dive through it in more detail, but looks already promising. Afterwards I will resolve this topic. Thx, for you effort already.